# working directory error in ant script - build.xml for classpathref

Tags: ant, path, build.xml

I have a build file in which I have a tasks as below

//tomcat stop ant script

```
When I run **tomcat-stop** task, instead of picking up the lib folder from tomcat server, it is trying to take my working directory.

I have set the project basedir as basedir=".". All my other tasks in the build file are working as expected but only in this scenario (tomcat-stop) I am finding an issue.

Error:

**C:\Dev\WebDev\XYZ\build.xml:103: C:\Dev\WebDev\XYZ\${build.tomcat.dir}\lib does not exist.**

I am using property file and everything from the property file is taken as expected. Also in the build.xml when I hover my mouse at the **classpathref="tomcat.class.path"**, it is showing all the files from tomcat lib but when I run the task I am getting the above error.

Entry in property file:
build.tomcat.dir=C:/TomcatServer

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
```

Comment: Can you post more of your build file? In particular, the tomcat-stop target and the import of the properties file.

Comment: Please find the files content in the question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your properties file is loaded inside the 'clean' target. If you just invoke the 'tomcat-stop' target on its own, the properties file is never loaded. Your other targets are working because they depend on 'clean'.

Try moving the line that loads your property file so that it is a direct child of the root element. i.e. not nested inside a target.

Comment: Excellent... I knew it was something stupid that I was doing but couldn't guess it. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: One more clarification... when I run the task tomcat-start, it is starting successfully but if there is any other targer after this tomcat-start target, I do not see the other task getting executed. Any idea on this and how to run some other tasks after tomcat-start?

Comment: A note to my clarification that I need... I am calling deploy and then tomcat-stop and then tomcat-start sequentially in another targer ie., using fork=true in both stop and start.

Comment: I'm not too sure what might be the problem or how you are invoking these targets. Its probably a good idea to post a new question for this problem.